# ssh login without any prompt

Tags: unix, ssh

I have to login more then 150 sever and execute some unix commands.
The problem is, if I create a script which will run from one server and ssh login to 150 server and execute cmds and exit. 
How can i login with any password prompt.
due to some reason i should not use ssh-keygen public and private key method , or use of some extra tool with bash line like "expect".

is there any normal way to do login through ssh in single command consisting username/password@servername like we have option in sqlplus and ftp.

Comment: No there's not. Either use a key (which you don't want to) or a tool like expect (which you don't want to either).

Comment: I would seriously question why you can't use those techniques (if this is not just some exercise).

Answer (score 4):

There is a utility called sshpass that allows you to specify a password in the commandline.

Under Ubuntu/Debian install by using `sudo apt-get install sshpass`

`sshpass -p 'abcedf' ssh joe@myserver.domain.com "df > ~/test; cat ~/test; rm ~/test;"`

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting up either `~/.shosts` or `/etc/ssh/shosts.equiv` on each of your remote hosts. See `man ssh` under "AUTHENTICATION" for details.